# Why is the Weyl tensor square gravity non-unitary?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, gravity, conformal-field-theory, unitarity

I want to understand constraints of unitarity in quantum field theory. There is quite folklore statement:

> gravity with a Weyl tensor square term is non-unitary

How to understand this? (I think that it is quite simple, because we rarely prove unitarity and it directly follows from action)

**How to modify theory to obtain unitary theory?**

Comment: Pretty interesting question. Do you have a reference with an example of this statement?

Comment: @RamiroHum-Sah, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_gravity